# inherit a role in Java Servlet 3.0

Tags: java, servlets, inheritance, mapping, role

Is it possible to inherit a role in Java Servlet 3.0 and how?

Let's say I have role A, B and C. In a servlet i have `if(request.isUserInRole("A")){ /* some feature only available for A */ }` and `if(request.isUserInRole("B")){ /* some feature only available for B */ }`. In web.xml are the roles defined:

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>A</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>B</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>C</role-name>
</security-role>
```

What I want is that every user with role C can do what A and B can without adding role A and B to user C.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it at the code level as same as you'd do for users with Roles A and B.

```
if(request.isUserInRole("C") { /* features available for both A and B */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `OR` operator:

```
if (request.isUserInRole("A") || request.isUserInRole("C")) {
 // will run if in group A or C
}
if (request.isUserInRole("B") || request.isUserInRole("C")) {
 // will run if in group B or C
}
if (request.isUserInRole("C")) {
 // will run only if in group C
}
```

### ...

If you are running 80 roles or so you should seriously consider defining some groups. A group is typically an enumeration which "holds" some roles and can be assigned to an entity (most probably user) in your model. Typical group hierarchies start with an anonymous group, which has a very restricted set of roles (or even only one role), go through e.g. ui_user, receiver, sender, content_editor and build up to user_admin, system_admin and super_admin.

Comment: It's not just A and B but +-80 roles. Solving it in an ugly and easier way would be adding all the roles to the users with role C in my database. Doing this would be error phrone with many users and different combinations. I want to make somewhere a mapping that C is a higher level than A and B and there for can do everything of A and B, and it applies to all users with role C.